# how to setup default runlevel to 3 after preseed install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: preseed, runlevel

how to setup default runlevel to 3 after preseed install ubuntu 16.04

I install an os ubuntu 16.04 with preseed.cfg 
on boot get stuck
boot stuck on /dev/sda1 clean
it seems the same question even the same about plymouth

please check out

https://www.linux.org/threads/boot-stuck-on-dev-sda1-clean.27627/

alt+F2 log in to the system.
I find the runlevel is 5 not 3
So how can I setup runlevel to 3 in preseed

because it is a server not a desktop.

try to fellow this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto#How_do_I_change_the_runlevel.3F

but I cannot find file /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf

```
ls /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf': No such file or directory
```

init 3 works

but I want defalut after a preseed install.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and other newer version of Linux, the concept of runlevel has been changed with systemd targets.

To change runlevel to 3, then use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl set-default runlevel3.target
```

For checking your current target, use the following command:

```
systemctl get-default
```

For more information you can visit systemd man pages.

```
man systemd
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.but the runlevel 3 and 5 is the same without desktop.I perfer 3 which is like other dist.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard
```

or:

```
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-server
```